# Is it wrong to leave a company shortly after starting?

Tags: job-change, job-offer, ethics

I am currently a contract employee for one company.  That company is ending my contract in the next week or so.  I have been interviewing at other places, some looking very promising as permanent positions.

My dilemma is that one place I am very interested in working for has an 8 week average interview/decision time and would require relocating my family should I get hired.  I may or may not even get asked to work there.  Other places I have interviewed with are local and would probably give me an offer within the next week or so (maybe before I need to file unemployment even).

What if the place I really want to work does make an offer though?  I feel bad if  I quit someplace that just hired me only a month or two after starting, but at the same time, the opportunity may never come again.  As an employer, would you understand why I would change, or would you be resentful for "wasting your time"?

Comment: My contract coming to an end was sudden.  Had i known it was going to end, I would have applied to the preferred company long ago.

Answer (score 1):

They could dump you overnight and if you live in a right-to-work state, without so much as an explanation, so don't get carried away with feeling bad that you are dumping the company after just two months - They are a going concern, they'll suck it up and get someone else. That's all there is to it. They were around before you came in, and they'll be around long after you leave. Hopefully.

If you get the offer and you decide to take off, seek to minimize the pain of their transitioning to a world without you. That's all there is to it. Life goes on. Ultimately, you are responsible and accountable for your career development and bettering the life of your family. No one else.